# Vertical align doesn't work, but should

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've read some articles on the internet stating that if an element is one of the following display types: `inline`, `inline-block`, or `table-cell`, then `vertical-align` should work. I created this Fiddle to check it out, but this doesn't seem true.

What are the ULTIMATE requirements that when followed, `vertical-align` always works?
Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YawDF/174/).

Comment: What fiddle did you create?

Comment: Do you want it centered or?

Comment: Sorry, just added the fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` on the outer div:

```
.a1{
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.a2 {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtRT/)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, do you know perhaps why my fiddle didn't work? It should?

Comment: I don't know, i never heard that vertical-align should work with `inline` or `inline-block`.... but you seem to be right. Here is a little explaination i found: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: I've read it there > under "What it actually does", number 1 on the list, here is the [article.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/)

Comment: Well the alignment only applies to the position related to inline text in which the elemnt is... as far as I know. See the point "Some Visuals" in the article.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer It seems to be all about the line height. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/axtRT/1/)

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 I never said I want to align something middle, my Fiddle represents `vertical-align: bottom`. Don't understand where the misunderstanding comes from.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 I see it, the description of the answer is something else than the answer itself, you can correct it if you'd like to.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 NVM, corrected it. Didn't know I could do it myself(rep).

Comment: PS. Your example works only if the outer div is not floated. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axtRT/2/)

Comment: @user3135147 Yes, that is because the use of `float` results in `display: block`. Wrap the element in another div which you can give the `float` then. http://jsfiddle.net/C74RK/

Comment: That's interesting. I went further and made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YawDF/185/) and the `paragraph` is aligned to the bottom. That's as if `div.a2` and `p` shared the same line and `div.a2` changed that line property for both elements, is that it or perhaps something else is going on?

Comment: `changed that line property` which line property do you mean?

Comment: Well this is how it looks like in my imagination [image.](http://i.imgur.com/EyF7ieF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use relative/absolute positioning instead of vertical-align.

```
.a1{
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

.a2 {
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/notme/YawDF/176/)